# Projection map in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, matrix, perspective

I need to set the two-point projection with matrix. I know about the use of function glFrustum and glOrtho but I need to set it via the matrix. How a can I do that?
I need use matrix like this

```
0.87    0    0.5   0
   0    1      0   0
   1    0  -1.73   1
 0.5    0  -0.87   2
```

Comment: the opengl docs derive the matrices that are produced with glortho, glfrustum etc, maybe start there...

Comment: What is a "two point projection matrix?"

Comment: @NicolBolas: I think OP refers to "two vanishing points perspective", e.g. http://www.automotiveillustrations.com/tutorials/drawing-2-point-perspective.html

Answer (score 0):

As @BeylerStudios mentioned in his/her comment, The OpenGL docs (for version 2.1) have the matrices for [glFrustum()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml) and [glOrtho()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml).

For example, the matrix for `glFrustum` looks like this:

```
(2 * nearVal)/(right - left)   0                            A  0
 0                            (2 * nearVal)/(top - bottom)  B  0
 0                             0                            C  D
 0                             0                           -1  0
```

where

```
A = (right + left)/(right - left)
B = (top + bottom)/(top - bottom)
C = -(farVal + nearVal)/(farVal - nearVal)
D = -(2 * farVal * nearVal)/(farVal - nearVal)
```

Comment: OT: is it possible to embed MathML or MathJax or something on SO? It's possible to use MathJax on math.SE, but doesn't seem to work for me here.

Comment: No, MathJax does not work on SO. It's either ASCII or an image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about the structure of matrix in glFrustum but as i said, I have to set myself the projection matrix like this(I update my question)

Comment: If you want to set it directly without `glFrustum()` or `glOrtho()`. After you set `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)`, call `glLoadMatrix()` https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml